# Let an and bn be cauchy. Is cn= [[x]] cauchy?

Tags: analysis

Let an and bn be cauchy. Is cn= [[x]] cauchy? 
Where [[x]] refers to the greatest integer less than or equal to x.

I know that we're trying to prove or disprove whether the floor function is a cauchy sequence.
I think it's false since the the floor of a negative number acts differently than the floor of a positive...but I'm very unsure about this. I'm not sure where to start

Comment: What do $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ have to do with $\{c\}$?

Comment: As stated you have a constant sequence so Cauchy sure. Also the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not used so why do you introduce them?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question was rather:

- if $(a_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence is $(c_n)_n$ also convergent, where $c_n=\lfloor a_n\rfloor$?

Your instinct was correct, the fact that the floor function has steps can hurt the convergence of $c_n$.

For instance, let's have (for $n>0$) $\quad a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}n\to 0$

Then $c_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n-1}2$ alternates values between $-1$ and $0$ depending wether $n$ is odd or even thus does not converge.

Of course, it is not confined to the behaviour around $0$, if you take $b_n=m+a_n$ with $m$ integer then $\lfloor b_n\rfloor$ suffers the same fate.

Comment: To the proposer: A function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous iff $(f(a_n))_n$ converges to $ f(a)$ whenever ($a_n)_n$ converges to $a.$ The floor function is (obviously) not continuous.